# Discord py MemberNotFound exception

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@commands.command()
async def mute(self, ctx, member : discord.Member = None):
  try:
    if isinstance(member, discord.Member):
      await member.edit(mute=True)

    elif member is None:  #setting the command to mute selected member        
    member=get(ctx.guild.members, id=Charles_id) 
      await member.edit(mute=True)        

  except discord.HTTPException:
    await ctx.channel.send(f"User {member.mention} isn't connected to voice channel")
  except discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound("@everyone"):
    vc = ctx.author.voice.channel
    for user in vc.members:  
      await user.edit(mute=True)
```

So I'm trying to make a command that mutes the mentioned player. By default its supposed to mute our
friend, Charles. The only problem was with default role (@Everyone). I struggled a lot but finally
I managed to come up with a working idea. Sadly it doesn't really work. The plan was to try getting member and
if member is @everyone it would run an error that would trigger except and would end up doing its' stuff.
I'm pretty new to programming so I hope to get a useful lesson, Cheers!

Traceback is below:

```
Ignoring exception in command ryj:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 903, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 851, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 786, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 697, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 552, in transform
    return await self.do_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 505, in do_conversion
    return await self._actual_conversion(ctx, converter, argument, param)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 451, in _actual_conversion
    ret = await instance.convert(ctx, argument)
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/converter.py", line 191, in convert
    raise MemberNotFound(argument)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MemberNotFound: Member "@​everyone" not found.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error speaks for itself. `@everyone` is not a member so you cant convert it.

Another option is to manually convert it:

```py
async def mute(self, ctx, *, member_string: str):
    if member_string == "@everyone":
        return await ctx.send("You can't mention everyone")
 
    # Converting the string to a `discord.Member` obj
    member = commands.MemberConverter.convert(ctx, member_string)
    if member.voice is None:
        return await ctx.send("Member isn't in a voicec channel") # Exiting if the user isn't connected to any vs channel

    await member.edit(mute=True)
```

Reference:

- [`MemberConverter.convert`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=memberconverter%20convert#discord.ext.commands.MemberConverter.convert)

Comment: It works perfectly, just had to add parentheses to .MemberConverter